# can't wget rpm oracle on centos linux

Tags: command-line, wget

Forgotten how I did this last time. Tried the following 2 methods that I thought had worked for me in the past:

*method #1*

```
$ wget \
    http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm
```

*method #2*

```
$ wget --no-cookies \
    --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
    "yourversion.rpm" \
    -O /opt/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm --no-check-certificate
```

But neither worked. For the time being I'll just download it the old fashion way but I'd like to be able to download it using `wget` as well.

Comment: IMHO You should write an Answer, instead of putting the answer in the Question. How are readers going to know that this is resolved without reading through the whole question as there is no answer marked Accepted?

Comment: I don't know, I have been too busy trying to work stuff out all day to give it any thought sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate                              \
    --no-cookies                                           \
    --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
    "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-i586.rpm"
```

If you truly want to dump this file to `/opt/jdk...` then you'll need to be root to write to that location. Just prefix the above command with `sudo`, and specify the output location, `-O "/opt/jdk-7-linux-i586.rpm"`.

```
$ sudo wget ... -O "/opt/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm"
```

Here's the full command:

```
$ sudo wget --no-check-certificate                         \
--no-cookies                                               \
--header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com"     \
-O "/opt/jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm"                          \
"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-i586.rpm"
```

#### References

- [How to automate download and instalation of Java JDK on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)

Comment: the above doesn't work though.

Comment: @CharlieBunt - strange, I ran that exact command and it did work for me. Did you get any kind of error message when you ran it?

Comment: yes I did get an error message but I can't remember what it was now. I tried it several times and it seemed to be going through but failed and it was big file so I just found it safer in the end to download from source straight to desktop.

Comment: @CharlieBunt - I'd be curious to see the error msgs. The above worked/works for me so something else must be going on.

Comment: I promise to recreate the error if you can add to this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110693/reboot-not-working-to-complete-shutdown-of-service

Comment: @CharlieBunt - I fixed a mistake I had in my original command. If you get a chance try it out and see if that works now.